If a sequence sums to 0, can another sequence that sums to 0 be found with bounded partial sums?
Let $\{a_i\}_1^n$ be a sequence of $n$ numbers in $\{1, \dots, M\}$.
Suppose there is a $\{s_i\}_1^n$ in $\{-1, 1\}$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i = 0$$
Prove or disprove: There is a sequence $\{ s'_i \}_1^n$ in $\{-1, 1\}$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s'_i = 0 \text{, and for all $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, } \left|\sum_{i=1}^j a_i s'_i\right| \leq M^2.$$
I thought about this for some time today and couldn't figure it out. I couldn't think of a counter example. But I also couldn't think of any reason this should be true.
The $M^2$ would be essentially sharp: consider the sequence of $M-1$ copies of $M$ followed by $M$ copies of $M-1$ when $M$ is even.
